# What does this icon mean

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, localhost

What does this icon mean. I know my question must be answer even without the image but how hahaha, Im creating a database, do I need additional code in my php to create connection with my database? "fcm" and "fcm_db" are my databases, I created it and I think somehow it auto generated that "fcm" that I highlightened.[image]

Comment: It's common name between the 2 databases. It is grouped by it. Group icon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a Group icon.

It displays when two or more databases start with the same name (prefix).
It has no effect on the database connection or anything.

Answer (score 1):

For your php code you need to specify the server where your database is located, then the username, and password this an example:

```
$dbname="fcm";
$servername="localhost"
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
else
$conn->query($sql);
```